# Appropriate sample size for weighted sample

Tags: sampling, sample-size, weighted-sampling, weighted-data

I have a population that is sampled such that each item has a different probability of being selected. That probability is separate and independent of the value of any given item.

How do I determine the appropriate number of samples needed such that the mean falls within an appropriate error interval?

Comment: You cannot be 100% sure that the population mean falls in a given interval.